# Syntax Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module (Dependency )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, package.json

SyntaxError:

```
 at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I try create my first React native app, but it show some ERROR. And I don't much about React native and there dependencies. I am self taught programmer about the ReactJS and JavaScript on YOUTUBE. And I searched for the ERROR and I can't find it out...

I expect to rectify my problem and Help me to create my first React native app.

Comment: Show us the code that resolves into this error, we cant help you with the given info.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @santhosh it seems you are importing the file with the wrong path and your path is going outside the src folder so this error is shown.